Applying for a Master's Degree with Less Than Perfect Credentials
I'm very interested in pursuing a master's degree at Perimeter Institute and consider applying in the next call. However, I am not an outstanding student. I also don't have a perfect GPA (My average is 7.98/10) and I was emotionally affected by the lockdown caused by the pandemic, which was reflected in my academic performance. However, I have managed to improve my CV and research experience a little this last year that I also completed university. I got an internship in a nearby country and I am currently working on a research project on gravitation that is expected to be published in a few months. I am also in a graduate-level online course and in the next few months I aim to obtain the TOEFL (or an English certification).
Even so, I read in forums like reddit that it is very difficult to get admitted and that they have rejected people with two or three articles in complex research areas. So I would like to receive comments or advice on how to improve my application or learn about the application experience of those who were or were not accepted. Finally I would like to clarify that, although I have more options, the PI is really something I would like to achieve

Normally, there is no such requirement for publications when applying for a masters degree. It is, however, appreciated that you come with some research experience and demonstrate it through a paper in a conference or journal. In some universities, there are pathways (or pre-degree there are different names for such programs) programs that are designed for the students who are actually not ready or suitable to start the mainstream courses. You can ask the admission officer at the institution if there is any such possibility there. If you are worried about the rejection due to your low GPA, consider the schools that offer pathway programs that could bridge your low GPA with mainstream studies by offering some extra courses. Hope it helps.

What do you mean when you mention specialized programs that could match my GPA? I don't know what type of programs you are referring to

Check this link for full list of universities/programs https://ssemw.org/education/universities-in-canada-that-accept-low-gpa-for-masters/
